# Finding Directional Derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, partial-derivative

I need to find a function $g(x,y,t)$ that it's polynomial with degree <=2, Such that the [Directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of
$f(x,y)=\int_{-7}^{8} g(x,y,t) dt$ in point $(2,7)$ with direction $u=\frac {-4}{97^{0.5}}i+\frac{9}{97^{0.5}}j$ is equal to 4.

How may I solve this kind of questions, are tried more than 50 functions and non worked, Should I really depend on luck and tries?

**Note:** The answer is expected to look like: $K_1x^2+K_2y^2+K_3t^2+K_4xy+K_5xt+K_6yt+K_7x+K_8y+K_9t+K_{10}$

Comment: 1. Take $g(x,y,t)$ in the form with $K_i$ mentioned above. 2. Integrate w.r.t. $t$ ($x$ and $y$ are parameters for that step) to obtain $f(x,y)$ 3. take $(\nabla\cdot f).u$ and equate to $4$. How many parameters of $K_i$ is left in the equation? Can you find a $g$ now?)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Sorry, I wasn't successful, may you show me a small example (It's okay to choose different numbers since I'm looking to learn and understand)

Comment: I am stuck on 3, how to do it?

Comment: I finished it after many calculations and it's wrong. I let all =0 but $K_4=(4(97^{0.5}))/270$

Comment: In the process Alexey outlined, what did you get for $\nabla f$? That will give us a hint as to where you messed up. I'm not sure what you mean by "I let all = 0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldn't be this hard. Let
$$g(x,y,t)=K_1x^2+K_2y^2+K_3t^2+K_4xy+K_5xt+K_6yt+K_7x+K_8y+K_9t+K_{10}$$
$$G(x,y,t)=\int g(x,y,t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\\
K_1x^2t+K_2y^2t+\frac13K_3t^3+K_4xyt+\frac12K_5xt^2+\frac12K_6yt^2+\\K_7xt+K_8yt+\frac12K_9t^2+K_{10}t+C$$
$$f(x,y)=G(x,y,8)-G(x,y,-7)=\\
15K_1x^2+15K_2y^2+285K_3+15K_4xy+\frac{15}{2}K_5x+\\
\frac{15}{2}K_6y+15K_7x+15K_8y+\frac{15}{2}K_9+15K_{10}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=30K_1x+15K_4y+\frac{15}{2}K_5+15K_7$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=30K_2y+15K_4x+\frac{15}{2}K_6+15K_8$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{(x,y)=(2,7)}=\\
(60K_1+105K_4+\frac{15}{2}K_5+15K_7,
210K_2+30K_4+\frac{15}{2}K_6+15K_8)$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{(x,y)=(2,7)}.u=\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{97}}\left(
-240K_1-420K_4-30K_5-60K_7
+1890K_2+270K_4+\frac{135}{2}K_6+135K_8
\right)$$
So if we let all but $K_4$ equal $0$ we'll have
$$-\frac{150}{\sqrt{97}}K_4=4\hbox{ thus }K_4=-\frac{2\sqrt{97}}{75}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found my mistake